# Google Places API

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, google-api

I'm trying to call Google Places API[1](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/index.html) using jQuery but it seems to be failing because of a cross-domain security issue. I've tried to make this request a JSONP request and it runs but the server returns straight up JSON so the parsing fails within jQuery. Has anyone found a solution for this?

```
var requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" +
                   location.coords.latitude + "," + location.coords.longitude + "&radius=100&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=<<api key here>>";

// Called with
$.getJSON(requestUrl + "&callback=?", onLocateRestaurants);
// or
$.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    callback: 'test',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: onLocateRestaurants2,
    error: defaultErrorHandler
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104122/querying-google-places-api-using-jquery

Comment: The Places API does not support JSON-P. See the question linked to by Ken above for more details.

Comment: Can you put these responses as answers so I can close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jeremy: I can post the closing answer for you.

The Places API does not support JSON-P. See the following question (as linked to by Ken Browning) for more details:

[Querying Google Places API using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104122/querying-google-places-api-using-jquery)