# Google Maps API V3 - Anyway to retrieve Autocomplete results instead of dropdown rendering it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I need to render the results of `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` in a custom way, instead of the default drop down menu.

Is there any way I can use the Google Maps API V3 to retrieve the same info of Autocomplete, but in an Array per request instead of the API do the rendering for me?

PS1:

I wondered I could use the `google.maps.places.PlaceSearchRequest`. But, differently from Autocomplete, it restricts my location. It cannot be used to search worldwide.

- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/index.html

PS2:

The default way I am (currently) using Autocomplete restricts me. I must pass an input element, and the API renders the dropdown, which I do NOT want.

```
var autocomplete, input_el, place_changed_trigger_func;
input_el = <an input element>;
place_changed_trigger_func = function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  // do whatever you want with place
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_el, {types: ["geocode"]});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', place_changed_trigger_func);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the link that @jegnag meant to include.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service

You can access the array of results (places in addition to suggested search terms), you can even add your own custom results to this array, and display everything however you choose.

Comment: I could not test it. But, looking at the documentation I guess this is exactly what I needed by that time. I am glad Google made it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you explored the [Autocomplete function](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html) of the Places API webservice? That appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeap, I had. But, it doesn't seem to scale very well. I'm looking for a "client <-> Google" solution, instead of a "client <-> my server <-> Google" way. Follow what I had tried before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104122/querying-google-places-api-using-jquery/8137086#8137086

Comment: @RafaelXavier, did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Hey @JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin, nope! Not yet :'(

Comment: @ManoMarks, you are the guy, do you know who can help us?

Comment: It appears that there isn't a way to get what you want. What you really want, I think, is a Places Search result that is unbounded, which Google doesn't provide.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [AutocompleteService class:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete)

*"You can use the AutocompleteService class to retrieve the query or place prediction data returned from the Autocomplete service. Calling either the getPlacePredictions() or getQueryPredictions() methods will return an array of five prediction objects of the form:"*