# Need place Google Auto Suggest within a city

Tags: google-maps, autosuggest, city

I have implemented Google Auto suggest API in my project. I am able to restrict it within a country(India).

But the client wants to restrict it within a city(Kolkata). When I type something in input box, places should appear within Kolkata not outside.

Is there any way to restrict it within a city?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(inputted citie name)&language=pt_BR&key=YOUR_API_KEY  use this  google api to get city locations

Answer (score 0):

From this [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types) documentation:

> You may restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a certain type by passing a `types` parameter. The parameter specifies a type or a type collection, as listed in the supported types below. If nothing is specified, all types are returned. **In general only a single type is allowed. The exception is that you can safely mix the geocode and establishment types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no types.**

You can try the country restriction then pass a `types: ['(cities)']` parameter:

**Example:**

```
function initialize() {

 var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

**Sample request:**
A request for cities containing "Vict" with results in Brazilian Portuguese:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(cities)&language=pt_BR&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Based from this [answer in the related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33236060/5832311), there is a feature request in public issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433.