# Can I get a only Dubai city address from Google Maps autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bounds, google-places-autocomplete

I tried this, but it also display the `Abu Dhabi` location which is out of Dubai. But I want the address in the `Dubai` area only.

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.1851804, 55.2780796) // Dubai area
);
var options = {
    bounds: defaultBounds,
    types: ['establishment'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'AE' }
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/41684903/11921403

Comment: @ShahzadB this is some kind of trick, i also tried it, but some place are missing in this trick. we can't use that. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real option with [Autocomplete](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete) is to use [componentRestrictions](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#ComponentRestrictions) to the country (as you are doing), then use [strictBounds](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.strictBounds).

For the bounds of Dubai, the geocoder returns bounds and viewport of: `{ north:25.3585607, east:55.5650393, south:24.7921359, west:54.8904543}` (the autocomplete API returns a viewport of the same, in `place.geometry.viewport`).

Bounds from Google Geocoder (square) vs. Bounds from [GADM](https://gadm.org/) (not square):
[image: bounds of Dubai from Google's Geocoder vs. from GADM]

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/veshox6z/)

[image: screenshot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var dubaiBounds = {
    north: 25.3585607,
    east: 55.5650393,
    south: 24.7921359,
    west: 54.8904543
  };
  map.fitBounds(dubaiBounds);
  var rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: dubaiBounds
  })

  var options = {
    bounds: dubaiBounds,
    types: ['establishment'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'AE'
    },
    strictBounds: true
  };
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  /// show on map
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
  autocomplete.setFields(
    ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pac-container">
  <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think in your case you need to pass the center parameter for example:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.1851804, 55.2780796),
```

the below link has a very good example:

https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-use-latlngbounds-google-maps.cfm

Comment: should i use `bounds` in this case ?

Comment: this is not working please understand my question first. the `center` property is use for `google.maps.Map` function.

Comment: with bounds, you specify  SouthWest point and northEast point and in your code above is just one point, so I assume what are you looking for is the center

Comment: As I mentioned if you need bounds to work you need to define 2 coordinates the southeast and northwest for example                                                                   
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['establishment']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

Comment: how can i found southeast and northwest of dbai location ?